# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageio.v3'

Tags: python, conda, stable-diffusion, python-imageio

## brief intro

I am adding an extension named **animatediff** to **Stable Diffusion**, and it turns out to be Error like the title says.

Here is the whole error code:

```
*** Error loading script: animatediff_output.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "I:\Github\stable-diffusion-webui-master\modules\scripts.py", line 382, in load_scripts
        script_module = script_loading.load_module(scriptfile.path)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "I:\Github\stable-diffusion-webui-master\modules\script_loading.py", line 10, in load_module
        module_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "I:\Github\stable-diffusion-webui-master\extensions\sd-webui-animatediff\scripts\animatediff_output.py", line 5, in <module>
        import imageio.v3 as imageio
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageio.v3'
```

By the way, I made this in conda and I have reinstalled imageio and relevant module for several times like this:

`pip install openpiv --upgrade --force-reinstall`

`conda install -c conda-forge imageio`

```
pip install imageio
pip install imageio[ffmpeg]
pip install imageio[pyav]
```

Besides, I use python to import `imageio` `imageio.v3` and it does not error:

```
(sdwebui) I:\Github\stable-diffusion-webui-master> python
Python 3.10.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Aug 22 2022, 20:30:19) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import imageio
>>> import imageio.v3 as imageio
>>> import nosuchmodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nosuchmodule'
```

and this is my version of stable diffusion:

```
•  version: 1.6.0  
•  python: 3.11.4  
•  torch: 2.0.1+cu118  
•  xformers: 0.0.20  
•  gradio: 3.41.2  
•  checkpoint: 31e35c80fc
```

so I really don't know what's wrong with the environment...

Comment: Are you sure the Stable Diffusion environment is the same one as the one you are creating in Conda? That is probably the problem.  How did you install the Stable Diffusion web UI?